# Lumia 535 suddenly loses all sound

Tags: lumia, sound, nokia-lumia-535

I just bought my Lumia 535 3 months ago. Recently, sound problem happened. I din't do anything, I just left it there, then, all sounds lost. No ringing, no app sound, nor even vibration. I've checked the sound setting, volume is still at max level. The only way to fix this is reset the phone (turn it off and on again by holding the POWER and VOLUME DOWN button).

This problem is very annoyed. Please help me to fix this. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried doing a hard reset? If that does not fix your problem it would suggest contacting the Microsoft service.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. In case the problem still exists, how can I contact Microsoft service?

Comment: I have this problem too. Sometimes the problem solve when I charge with usb cable of other device.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it a few seconds ago..to solve this,first try to blow the speakers..really hard..second,knock gently or really hard beside the speakers.

I found this trick on http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Lumia/no-sound-from-my-nokia-lumia-720/td-p/1935826/page/2

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when it happens again. So, this is a hardware problem?